# Autocompletado django en visual studio code

Tags: django, vscode

estoy teniendo un problema y es que como tengo un nuevo portatil volvi a instalar arch linux y visual studio code, pero cuando volvi a instalar el software el autocompletado de visual studio code para django no me funciona, pues para python si lo hace sin problemas pero a la hora de trabajar con django las opciones del framework no funcionan, es decir cuando trabajo con vistas basadas en clases no me genera el autocompletado, como template_name, form_class, etc.., igualmente asi mismo con los modelos no genera la ayuda de max_length, y esas demas cosas del framework, tengo seleccionado el interprete pero no me funciona y tambien python:build workspace symbols y nada.
de ante mano agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Hola, aunque la pregunta parece válida para el sitio, ha sido reportada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Considera añadir algo más de información, indica si recibes algún error (y cuál), etc. Lee [ask] para más recomendaciones sobre cómo mejorar tus preguntas.

Comment: si entiendo, y pues creo que en la pregunta fue claro pues no me genera ningun error en si el editor, pero la ayuda es decir el autocompletado que deberia de dar al momento de instalar django no lo hace mas la ayuda de python si